# How to read data HTML AGILITY PACK

Tags: html-agility-pack

i was wondering that how can we read data in this website http://www.whatismyip.com/automation/n09230945.asp
to check my IP?
like there is no tab no body nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in this case, you don't need to parse anything, you just need to get an HTTP request and get the stream, like this:

```
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.whatismyip.com/automation/n09230945.asp");
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
    }
```

If you really want to use Html Agility Pack, this is the equivalent:

```
    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    Console.WriteLine(web.Load("http://www.whatismyip.com/automation/n09230945.asp").DocumentNode.OuterHtml);
```